# Use MATLAB to double a parameter until a certain value

Tags: matlab

I want to double a parameter (population size) until it reaches a certain value, regardless of the number of loops (generations). Say I have the following loop:

```
population_size = 10; %initial population size    

for i = 0:10,     %no. of generations
   %(*call function for model*) 
   population_size = (population_size*2);
   gene_frequency = (gene_frequency*population_size)/population_size;
end
```

How would I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Err -- use `break` within the loop, within a condition statement. Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: Replace the `for` loop with a `while` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yvon has suggested, use a `while` loop that will keep looping until you meet a certain condition.  I can see that your population size is doubling, and so you want to make the `while` loop until is it equal to, or exceeds this number.

I do have one question though: Your `gene_frequency` call seems useless.  You are taking the variable, multiplying by `population_size`, then dividing by `population_size`.... and you'll just get the same number as you did last time.  I'm going to leave this statement out as it doesn't contribute anything meaningful to your question.

As such:

```
population_size = 10; %initial population size    
target_population = ... ;%// You place the population you want met here

while population_size < target_population %// NEW
   %//(*call function for model*) 
   population_size = (population_size*2);
end
```

---

## Edit - July 30th, 2014

You have mentioned in your comments that you want to run this for 15 generations, but when the population size reaches its limit, it will remain the same for the rest of the generations.  You can combine this with a `for` loop and an `if` statement.  We will go through each generation, then check to see what the population size is.  As long as the population size is less than the target population, we will double the size.  Once it finally exceeds the population size, this will no longer double but the loop will keep going until go through the rest of the generations.

You can do this like so:

```
population_size = 10; %initial population size    
target_population = ... ;%// You place the population you want met here

for gen = 1 : 15
   %//(*call function for model*) 
   if (population_size <= target_population)
       population_size = (population_size*2);
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful @rayryeng.  If I want the generations to continue even after the target population size is reached do I use 'else'? Let's say there are 15 generations but the max population size is 10,000 (so this would be reached after only 10 generations - the model would keep going but the populations size would not increase). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2861089 - I don't quite understand your question.  How many more times do you want this to keep going after the `while` loop ends?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. An example might be: initial_population size=10; target_population size = 10000;
for i = 0:15, %no. of generations
while initial_population_size < target_population_size
%call function for model
initial_population_size = (initial_population_size*2); else initial_population_size = initial_population_size %obviously wrong!  
end
end

Comment: @user2861089 - If you already know how many times the loop is going to execute, then change the `while` loop to a `for`.  As such, just do `for i = 1 : 15 <insert your code here> population_size = 2*population_size; end`.  This loop will run 15 times.

Comment: thanks, I want the population size to double until it reaches the target size however I want the loop to keep running, i.e. the loop runs for 15 generations even if the target size is reached after only 10 generations - the population simply does not grow after it reaches its target but the loop continues for the number of generations specified. Once it has reached its target (10,000), this will be the constant population size for the remaining generations.

Comment: OK, you would have to use a `for` loop combined with an `if` statement.  I'll modify my post.

Comment: @user2861089 - Done.  Good luck.